# Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, crossed-random-effects

Here is how I have understood nested vs. crossed random effects:

**Nested random effects** occur when a lower level factor appears only within a particular level of an upper level factor.

- For example, pupils within classes at a fixed point in time.
- In `lme4` I thought that we represent the random effects for nested data in either of two equivalent ways:

  ```
  (1|class/pupil)  # or  
  (1|class) + (1|class:pupil)
  ```

**Crossed random effects** means that a given factor appears in more than one level of the upper level factor.

- For example, there are pupils within classes measured over several years.
- In `lme4`, we would write:

  ```
  (1|class) + (1|pupil)
  ```

However, when I was looking at a particular nested dataset, I noticed that both model formulas gave identical results (code and output below). However I have seen other datasets where the two formulas produced different results.  So what is going on here?

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://web.archive.org/web/20160624172041if_/http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bwest/classroom.csv")
# (the data is no longer at `http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bwest/classroom.csv`
# hence the link to web.archive.org)
# Crossed version: 
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: mathgain ~ (1 | schoolid) + (1 | classid)
   Data: mydata

REML criterion at convergence: 11768.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6441 -0.5984 -0.0336  0.5334  5.6335 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classid  (Intercept)   99.23   9.961  
 schoolid (Intercept)   77.49   8.803  
 Residual             1028.23  32.066  
Number of obs: 1190, groups:  classid, 312; schoolid, 107


# Nested version:
Formula: mathgain ~ (1 | schoolid/classid)

REML criterion at convergence: 11768.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6441 -0.5984 -0.0336  0.5334  5.6335 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classid:schoolid (Intercept)   99.23   9.961  
 schoolid         (Intercept)   77.49   8.803  
 Residual                     1028.23  32.066  
Number of obs: 1190, groups:  classid:schoolid, 312; schoolid, 107
```

Answer (score 364, accepted):

(This is a fairly long answer, there is a summary at the end)

You are not wrong in your understanding of what nested and crossed random effects are in the scenario that you describe. However, your definition of crossed random effects is a little narrow. A more general definition of crossed random effects is simply: **not nested**. We will look at this at the end of this answer, but the bulk of the answer will focus on the scenario you presented, of classrooms within schools.

First note that:

**Nesting is a property of the data, or rather the experimental design, not the model.**

Also,

**Nested data can be encoded in at least 2 different ways, and this is at the heart of the issue you found.**

The dataset in your example is rather large, so I will use another schools example from the internet to explain the issues. But first, consider the following over-simplified example:

[image]

Here we have classes nested in schools, which is a familiar scenario. The important point here is that, between each school, the classes have the same identifier, **even though they are distinct if they are nested**. `Class1` appears in `School1`, `School2` and `School3`. However if the data are nested then `Class1` in `School1` is *not* the same unit of measurement as `Class1` in `School2` and `School3`. If they were the same, then we would have this situation:

[image]

which means that every class belongs to every school. The former is a nested design, and the latter is a crossed design (some might also call it multiple membership. **Edit: For a discussion of the differences between multiple membership and crossed random effects, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487039/multiple-membership-vs-crossed-random-effects/487047#487047)** ), and we would formulate these in `lme4` using:

`(1|School/Class)` or equivalently `(1|School) + (1|Class:School)`

and

`(1|School) + (1|Class)`

respectively. Due to the ambiguity of whether there is nesting or crossing of random effects, it is very important to specify the model correctly as these models will produce different results, as we shall show below. Moreover, it is not possible to know, just by inspecting the data, whether we have nested or crossed random effects. This can only be determined with knowledge of the data *and* the experimental design.

But first let us consider a case where the Class variable is coded uniquely across schools:

[image]

There is no longer any ambiguity concerning nesting or crossing.  The nesting is explicit. Let us now see this with an example in R, where we have 6 schools (labelled `I`-`VI`) and 4 classes within each school (labelled `a` to `d`):

```
> dt <- read.table("https://web.archive.org/web/20171010101537if_/http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt",
                   header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
> # update 1: Data was previously publicly available from
> # http://researchsupport.unt.edu/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt
> # but the link is now broken. 
> # update 2: The link is broken again. A new link is used. The previous link was: http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt
> xtabs(~ school + class, dt)

        class
school  a  b  c  d
   I   50 50 50 50
   II  50 50 50 50
   III 50 50 50 50
   IV  50 50 50 50
   V   50 50 50 50
   VI  50 50 50 50
```

We can see from this cross tabulation that every class ID appears in every school, which satisfies your definition of crossed random effects (in this case we have *fully*, as opposed to *partially*, crossed random effects,  because every class occurs in every school). So this is the same situation that we had in the first figure above. However, if the data are really nested and not crossed, then we need to explicitly tell `lme4`:

```
> m0 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school/class), data = dt)
> summary(m0)

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 class:school (Intercept)  8.2043  2.8643  
 school       (Intercept) 93.8421  9.6872  
 Residual                  0.9684  0.9841  
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  class:school, 24; school, 6

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 60.2378227  4.0117909  15.015
open         0.0061065  0.0049636   1.230
agree       -0.0076659  0.0056986  -1.345
social       0.0005404  0.0018524   0.292

> m1 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school) + (1 |class), data = dt)
summary(m1)

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 school   (Intercept) 95.887   9.792   
 class    (Intercept)  5.790   2.406   
 Residual              2.787   1.669   
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  school, 6; class, 4

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 60.198841   4.212974  14.289
open         0.010834   0.008349   1.298
agree       -0.005420   0.009605  -0.564
social      -0.001762   0.003107  -0.567
```

As expected, the results differ because `m0` is a nested model while `m1` is a crossed model.

Now, if we introduce a new variable for the  class identifier:

```
> dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")
> xtabs(~ school + classID, dt)

      classID
school I.a I.b I.c I.d II.a II.b II.c II.d III.a III.b III.c III.d IV.a IV.b
   I    50  50  50  50    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0
   II    0   0   0   0   50   50   50   50     0     0     0     0    0    0
   III   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    50    50    50    50    0    0
   IV    0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0   50   50
   V     0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0
   VI    0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0

      classID
school IV.c IV.d V.a V.b V.c V.d VI.a VI.b VI.c VI.d
   I      0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   II     0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   III    0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   IV    50   50   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   V      0    0  50  50  50  50    0    0    0    0
   VI     0    0   0   0   0   0   50   50   50   50
```

The cross tabulation shows that each level of class occurs only in one level of school, as per your definition of nesting. This is also the case with your data, however it is difficult to show that with your data because it is very sparse. Both model formulations will now produce the same output (that of the nested model `m0` above):

```
> m2 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school/classID), data = dt)
> summary(m2)

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classID:school (Intercept)  8.2043  2.8643  
 school         (Intercept) 93.8419  9.6872  
 Residual                    0.9684  0.9841  
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  classID:school, 24; school, 6

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 60.2378227  4.0117882  15.015
open         0.0061065  0.0049636   1.230
agree       -0.0076659  0.0056986  -1.345
social       0.0005404  0.0018524   0.292

> m3 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school) + (1 |classID), data = dt)
> summary(m3)

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classID  (Intercept)  8.2043  2.8643  
 school   (Intercept) 93.8419  9.6872  
 Residual              0.9684  0.9841  
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  classID, 24; school, 6

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 60.2378227  4.0117882  15.015
open         0.0061065  0.0049636   1.230
agree       -0.0076659  0.0056986  -1.345
social       0.0005404  0.0018524   0.292
```

It is worth noting that crossed random effects do not have to occur within the same factor - in the above the crossing was completely within school. However, this does not have to be the case, and very often it is not. For example, sticking with a school scenario, if instead of classes within schools we have pupils within schools, and we were also interested in the doctors that the pupils were registered with, then we would also have nesting of pupils within doctors. There is no nesting of schools within doctors, or vice versa, so this is also an example of crossed random effects, and we say that schools and doctors are crossed. A similar scenario where crossed random effects occur is when individual observations are nested within two factors simultaneously, which commonly occurs with so-called repeated measures *subject-item* data. Typically each subject is measured/tested multiple times with/on different items and these same items are measured/tested by different subjects. Thus, observations are clustered within subjects *and* within items, but items are not nested within subjects or vice-versa. Again, we say that subjects and items are *crossed*.

**Summary: TL;DR**

The difference between crossed and nested random effects is that nested random effects occur when one factor (grouping variable) appears only within a particular level of another factor (grouping variable). This is specified in `lme4` with:

`(1|group1/group2)`

where `group2` is nested within `group1`.

Crossed random effects are simply: *not nested*. This can occur with three or more grouping variables (factors) where one factor is separately nested in both of the others, or with two or more factors where individual observations are nested separately within the two factors. These are specified in `lme4` with:

`(1|group1) + (1|group2)`

Comment: +6, this is a really nice answer. Remind me in a couple of days & I'll put a bounty on it.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Is there a name for a possibly third type of experimental design where you create unique levels for two factors (possibly nested), so if I followed cohorts purchasing motorcycles from different dealers within different cities, how would I communicate to readers that I've basically created a single level factor `interaction(city, dealer)`?

Comment: @AdamO I'm not sure about that. What do you mean by "followed" (are there repeated measures?) I'd need a bit more info and ideally some sample data.

Comment: @AdamO That seems unwise, because it doesn't reflect that the effect of dealer 1 in city 1 should be more like that of dealer 2 in city 1 than dealer 3 in city 2.

Comment: +6, this is such a great answer that I felt I could top up @gung's bounty with another one. By the way, I am struggling with what probably is a very basic confusion ([here is my Q](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232109/)) and would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @amoeba thank you so much. Out of sheer coincidence I was just reading your very nice Q when you wrote this comment ! It's quite thought provoking and invokes some philosophical ideas about what is random and fixed in the mixed models framework. I want to answer it and will do so as soon as I can. Thanks again !

Comment: @RobertLong It seems that split plot (repeated measures) designs are often called "nested" even though they are not really nested according to this answer of yours. This terminological inconsistency has probably contributed to my confusion in the linked question. Would be great if you could clarify it, either here or there. I am even thinking whether I should post a separate (not R oriented) terminological question about what is nested in split plots.

Comment: @amoeba you may be right that there is a terminology difference between the classical anova / experimental design approaches and the more general mixed model/multilevel model approaches - do you have any reference to the use of *nested* in split plot set up ?

Comment: @RobertLong I have only been reading about it on the Web (so cannot say what is written in books), but here is for example [Wikipedia on split-plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_randomization). See also ["split plots are nested"](https://www.google.pt/?ion=1&espv=2&client=ubuntu#q=%22split+plots+are+nested%22) google search. Or here on CV the first sentence of [this answer by @Placidia](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/39242/28666). Let me know if you think it makes sense to post a separate question.

Comment: Update to my previous comment. I have checked two old & authoritative books on experimental design: Maxwell and Delaney, 1990, Designing Experiments and Analyzing Data, and Montgomery, 1976, Design and Analysis of Experiments. Both talk about nested designs and both talk about repeated measures aka split-plots; both use the word "nested" *only* in the sense you are using it and never refer to repeated measures as nested. So I don't think there is any terminology difference after all.

Comment: Such a great answer!. Could you answer my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275450/when-to-use-mixed-effect-model) derived from this? Thanks!

Comment: This is such a helpful answer - I keep returning to it when I get confused about the topic. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RobertLong, did you mean to write “(1|School/Class) or equivalently (1|School) + (1|School:Class)”, or does the order not make any difference? Thank you!

Comment: @Ivan the order does not make any difference. `School:Class` is the same as `Class:School`

Comment: Robert, still a great answer! I Is [*this situation*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465699/analyzing-a-computer-adaptive-test-in-r?noredirect=1#465699) is an example of partially crossed design?

Comment: @Reza thanks, and yes it looks that way !

Comment: Dear Robert, do you have any perspectives on [**this issue**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467006/longitudinal-analysis-a-cluster-switched-from-control-to-treatment-in-r)?

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, partially crossed also means partially nested in this context.

Comment: @rnorouzian I think the dataset was given by the questioner. Classes in schools is a canonical example of nesting. In this answer I am not saying they are crossed. I am trying to point out that nesting is a property of the experimental design and can't always be inferred from the data due to the way variables are encoded. As always in applied statistics, context is vital.

Comment: Hi Robert, for the 3 models you discuss [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/477354/140365), could we use `(1|x/y)` format in any way? Also, when you say `(1|School/Class)` is equivalent to `(1|School) + (1|Class:School)` does that mean that from the perspective of `lme4` nesting means that the higher structure (`school`) must have a random-intercept purely AS WELL AS in combination with the lower structure (`class`)?

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, in the 2nd model in the linked post, we could use `(time | therapist/subjects)` instead of `(time | therapist:subjects) + (time | therapist)`. And yes again your understanding is correct in the way that nesting is specified - we always need random intercepts for the higher level factor (assuming that there is variation at that level), along with random interecepts for the *unique* lower level factor, but this is not specific to `lme4` - it is more of a general mixed model thing

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! When you say *we always need random intercepts for the higher level factor, along with random intercepts for the **unique** lower level factor*, can you please clarify what do you mean by **unique**? Is that why we show nesting in the second term of `(1|School) + (1|Class:School)` as `Class:School` (combinations)?

Comment: @RobertLong Hi Robert, how would you introduce a predictor about the group level, such as a characteristic about the school (e.g., percentage of professors with PhDs...)? Simply as another explanatory variable in the model?

Comment: @CharlieGlez Yes, that is correct. With mixed models you don't need to tell the software what "level" the predictor varies (unlike some multilevel modelling software where you do). You simply include it as a fixed effect, like any other.

Comment: Dear Robert, I had a [follow-up question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/534858/140365) on your above answer.

Comment: I would just like to add to the chorus of commenters and say that this is a truly great answer. Nesting vs crossing in mixed effect models confounds many (myself included, at times), and your answer lays out the distinction beautifully.

Comment: @jdobres Thank you. Glad it could help !

Comment: Hi @RobertLong. I really enjoyed and understood your answer to this topic. Could I possibly have your opinion about this, please? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568927/lmer-and-binary-data-input?noredirect=1#comment1049539_568927

Comment: Dear Robert, I was wondering if you could possibly comment on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/635312/284623)?

Comment: This is quite a Robert Long answer, thanks!

Comment: @kaushik I’m not sure what a *“Robert Long answer”* is, but I will take it as a compliment :) Thank you!

Comment: The link seems to be broken again, you may use [this Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171010101537if_/http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt) instead.

By the way, awesome answer Robert! Learned a lot.